# The ball of radius one with center at $(0,0,0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ consists of $(0,0,0,0,0)$ and all the words weight one. For $w=(1,0,1,1,0)$,

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

definition : Let $w$ be a word in $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ and $r$ a natural number. The ball of radius $r$ with center $w$, denoted by $B_{r}(w)=\{x \in \mathbb{F}_{q}^{n} : d(w,x) \leq r\}$ .

Now there is an example ( which I don't understand) The ball of radius one with center at $(0,0,0,0,0)$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ consists of $(0,0,0,0,0)$ and all the words weight one. For $w=(1,0,1,1,0)$,

$B_{1}(w)=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0\\
1\\
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right)^{tr}$,
$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1\\
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right)^{tr}$
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right)^{tr}$, 
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}
\right)^{tr}$,
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right)^{tr}$, 
$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right)
$

would someone please explain this example to me. Thank you

Comment: How is $d$ defined here?

Comment: $\mid w-x \mid $

Comment: The Hamming distance between $x$ and $y$, denoted by $d(x,y)$, is the number of $i$ such that $a_{i} \neq b_{i}$

Answer (score 1):

Your ball of radius one with center $w$ consists of $w$ and all the words at distance one from $w$ (Hamming distance).